# Understanding `option long_options[]` when using `getopt_long`

Tags: c, parameter-passing, command-line-arguments, getopt, getopt-long

I am trying to learn to use `getopt_long`. From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getopt#Example_2_.28using_GNU_extension_getopt_long.29), I see the code

```
#include <stdio.h>     /* for printf */
#include <stdlib.h>    /* for exit */
#include <getopt.h>    /* for getopt_long; POSIX standard getopt is in unistd.h */
int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    int c;
    int digit_optind = 0;
    int aopt = 0, bopt = 0;
    char *copt = 0, *dopt = 0;
    static struct option long_options[] = {
        {"add", 1, 0, 0},
        {"append", 0, 0, 0},
        {"delete", 1, 0, 0},
        {"verbose", 0, 0, 0},
        {"create", 1, 0, 'c'},
        {"file", 1, 0, 0},
        {NULL, 0, NULL, 0}
    };
    int option_index = 0;
    while ((c = getopt_long(argc, argv, "abc:d:012",
                 long_options, &option_index)) != -1) {
        int this_option_optind = optind ? optind : 1;
        switch (c) {
        case 0:
            printf ("option %s", long_options[option_index].name);
            if (optarg)
                printf (" with arg %s", optarg);
            printf ("\n");
            break;
        case '0':
        case '1':
        case '2':
            if (digit_optind != 0 && digit_optind != this_option_optind)
              printf ("digits occur in two different argv-elements.\n");
            digit_optind = this_option_optind;
            printf ("option %c\n", c);
            break;
        case 'a':
            printf ("option a\n");
            aopt = 1;
            break;
        case 'b':
            printf ("option b\n");
            bopt = 1;
            break;
        case 'c':
            printf ("option c with value '%s'\n", optarg);
            copt = optarg;
            break;
        case 'd':
            printf ("option d with value '%s'\n", optarg);
            dopt = optarg;
            break;
        case '?':
            break;
        default:
            printf ("?? getopt returned character code 0%o ??\n", c);
        }
    }
    if (optind < argc) {
        printf ("non-option ARGV-elements: ");
        while (optind < argc)
            printf ("%s ", argv[optind++]);
        printf ("\n");
    }
    exit (0);
}
```

I don't quite understand the `option long_options[]` object.

**First column**

I think the first "column" of `long_options[]` should be the long flag (whatever follows `--`) the user have used in the command line.

**Second column**

I would have thought the second column should contain only `no_argument`, `required_argument`, or `optional_argument` but instead of that I see 0 and 1.

**Third column**

I don't understand the third column.

**Fourth column and maximum number of flags**

The fourth column is the unique identifier one uses in the switch statement. However, if the unique identifier can only be a single character, then are we limited to all lower case letters (26) + all uppercase letters (26) + the numbers (10) + eventually some special characters for a total of a bit more than 62 different arguments max? Is this a limitation of `getopt`? If I am mistaken, then how can one indicate more than two characters to identify a flag in the third argument to `getopt_long` (`""abc:d:012""`)

I suppose the last row of `option long_options[]` is for when `getopt` returns `-1` and therefore does not really matter as long as it exists.

Comment: C++ Is not C...

Comment: I suppose you are reffering to my use of the tag `C`. That was a mistake, I meant `C++`. (tag edited). Thanks

Comment: @Remi.b You had it as C++ the first time. amanuel2 edited your question to change the C++ tag to C. The code works in either language. If you're trying to understand it specifically as C++ code, the C++ tag is appropriate, just beware that the code does not demonstrate C++ best practices and you will likely receive comments about that.

Comment: @hvd Oh ok, that makes sense. I am aiming to code in C++ but I will be happy to understand how `getopt` works in pure `C` and I'll consider later best practices in `C++`. I edited the tag back to `C`. Thank you

Comment: @Remi.b i edited it to `C` , because `C++` isn't really being used here.. as you are using `printf` and so on.. I assumed you mistagged and put it as `C++`.

Comment: Wikipedia is not the manual; which part of the manual for [`getopt_long()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt-Long-Options.html#Getopt-Long-Options) is causing problems?

Comment: There's no reason to guess about the meanings of the members of `struct option`.  Refer to the real documentation of `getopt_long()`, available in many places, apparently not including Wikipedia.  [Here](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt_long), for instance, or [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt-Long-Options.html), not to mention probably on your own machine via the `man` command.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `struct option` array is precisely defined in [`man getopt_long`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html) [Note 1] from which I excerpt:

> `longopts` is a pointer to the first element of an array of `struct option` declared in `<getopt.h>` as
>
> ```
>    struct option {
>        const char *name;
>        int         has_arg;
>        int        *flag;
>        int         val;
>    };
> ```
>
> The meanings of the different fields are:
>
> *`name`*   is the name of the long option.
>
> *`has_arg`* is:  `no_argument`  (or  0) if the option does not take an argument; `required_argument` (or 1) if the option requires an argument; or `optional_argument` (or 2) if the option takes an optional argument.
>
> *`flag`*   specifies how results are returned for a long option.  If flag is `NULL`, then `getopt_long()` returns `val`.  (For example, the calling program  may set `val` to the equivalent short option character.)  Otherwise, `getopt_long()` returns 0, and `flag` points to a variable which is set to `val` if the option is found, but left unchanged if the option is not found.
>
> *`val`*    is the value to return, or to load into the variable pointed to by `flag`.
>
> The last element of the array has to be filled with zeros.

So, you would normally use a symbolic constant for the second element (`has_arg`), but the manpage allows you to use 0, 1 or 2, presumably for backwards-compatibility. (Wikipedia should use the symbolic constants, IMHO, but that's between Wikipedia and its editors.)

`getopt_long` returns an `int`, not a `char`. If the `flag` (third) field is `NULL` (or, equivalently, 0), then the `val` (fourth) field will be returned, and that can be anything which fits into an `int`. A character certainly fits into an `int`, so you could return the equivalent short option character (as noted in the manpage) but you are under no obligation to do so. `getopt` also returns an `int`, but since it always returns an option character (or an error indication), there are a large number of `int` values which it will never return. [Note 2]

If the third field is not `NULL`, it is expected to point to a variable of type `int` into which `getopt_long` will store the `val` value. That could be used, for instance, for boolean flags:

```
enum FROBNICATE { FROB_UNSET = -1, FROB_NO = 0, FROB_YES = 1 };
/* ... */

/* This is conceptually an enum, but `getopt_long` expects an int */
int frob_flag = FROB_UNSET;

struct option long_opts = {
  /* ... */
  {"frobnicate", no_argument, &frob_flag, FROB_YES},
  {"unfrobnicated", no_argument, &frob_flag, FROB_NO},
  /* ... */
  {NULL, 0, NULL, 0}
};

/* Loop over arguments with getopt_long;
   In the switch statement, you can ignore the returned value
   0 because the action has been fully realized by setting the
   value of a flag variable.
 */

if (frob_flag == FROB_UNSET)
  frob_flag = get_default_frobnication();
```

As indicated by the manpage, the last entry in the array must be all zeros (or `NULL` for the pointer members). That is needed so that `getopt_long` knows where the array ends.

#### Notes

1. You probably have the manpages installed on your system, in which case you can simply type `man getopt_long` to see the documentation for `getopt_long`. That should work for any standard C library function, any Gnu libc function, and, in general, any C library function for which you have installed the `-doc` package. (Highly recommended.) On the whole, you should try a manpage *first* before looking at Wikipedia, because the manpage will be the documentation for the version of the library function actually installed on your system.
2. The fact that a function returns a given datatype does not imply that it might return any possible value of that datatype.

Comment: Using an enum as a flag does not seem to work in C++. I get a `error: cannot convert 'FROBNICATE*' to 'int*'`. How should I work around this?

Comment: It looks to me like g++ should be making an implicit conversion from the unscoped enum to int*. Even explicitly setting the type to `int` does not work: `enum FROBNICATE : int { FROB_UNSET = -1, FROB_NO = 0, FROB_YES = 1 };`

Comment: @Mike: My bad, and it will be much more evident in C++ because it's (correctly) pickier about enums. SInce `option::flag` has type `int*`, the variable you store the flag value in  needs to be an `int`, even if its value is conceptually an enum. If you use type safe enums in C++ then you'll need to add casts as well, which would be annoying. I changed the type in the answer, but no casts (since the question is still C). Thanks.